# How does Angular's injector obtain its omniscience?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following example is lifted from the angularJS docs http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

In this example somehow the injector knows **$timeout** by name and **dateFilter** by name, even though javascript doesn't have named parameters (like Python).  So I added a debugger statement, to see how it manages to pull this magic off, and walking back 10 so stack frames, I come to the conclusion I'm completely lost!

I see this all over the place in angular, this magical injector that somehow manages to get the right pieces marshalled together for function calls.  I just don't understand how they do it.  My directive could as easily have $location, or something else as the first argument to the function and it would get the right object so that it would work.  How does the magic work????

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="docsTimeDirective">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  debugger;
  angular.module('docsTimeDirective', [])
    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
      $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
    })
    .directive('myCurrentTime', function($timeout, dateFilter) {
      debugger;

      ...

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr/>
    Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all happens in the following piece of code, which basically uses toString() on the function you pass as a factory to angular, and which extracts the argument names from this string representation of the function using regular expressions:

```
var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var $injectorMinErr = minErr('$injector');
function annotate(fn) {
  var $inject,
      fnText,
      argDecl,
      last;

  if (typeof fn == 'function') {
    if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
      $inject = [];
      if (fn.length) {
        fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
        argDecl = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
        forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg){
          arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name){
            $inject.push(name);
          });
        });
      }
      fn.$inject = $inject;
    }
  } else if (isArray(fn)) {
    last = fn.length - 1;
    assertArgFn(fn[last], 'fn');
    $inject = fn.slice(0, last);
  } else {
    assertArgFn(fn, 'fn', true);
  }
  return $inject;
}
```

Comment: fn.toString()?  It never occurred to me that was a language feature, I had just assumed it was part of devtools.  Coming from a C++ background, this was totally unsuspected!